# Google Cloud Endpoints Setup Trouble

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm completely new to Google's Cloud Platform and I'm having trouble setting it up for my Android device. I am attempting to follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloWorld) and I'm at the point of trying to test my backend with my Android Emulator. The emulator, however, gives me [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptg91.jpg) after 20 seconds, Where instead it should say my name. Here's my code so far:

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    buildUI();

    new EndpointsAsyncTask().execute(new Pair<Context, String>(this, "Solomon"));


}
```

EndpointsAsyncTask.java

```
public class EndpointsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<Context, String>, Void, String> {
private static MyApi myApiService = null;
private Context context;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Pair<Context, String>... params) {
    if(myApiService == null) {  // Only do this once
        MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                // options for running against local devappserver
                // - 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
                // - turn off compression when running against local devappserver
                .setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")
                .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                    @Override
                    public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                        abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                    }
                });
        // end options for devappserver

        myApiService = builder.build();
    }

    context = params[0].first;
    String name = params[0].second;

    try {
        return myApiService.sayHi(name).execute().getData();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

All Help is appreciated!

**EDIT: Part of the problem was that I was running Endpoints Backend rather than the App Engine Servlet Backend. But now I'm now getting "connection refused" and I am running the App Engine Servlet Backend. Any Ideas?**

Comment: Solomon please point your browser to http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/explorer are all your endpoints there?

Comment: @jirungaray I went to that link in my browser, but it tells me that "This Webpage is not available".

Comment: Ok so the problem is not you client, your server is not running correctly. Please include include what build system ( eclipse, maven?) you are using and include the endpoint source.

Comment: You may need to set your address in the dev server, which only listens to localhost by default. Since you're trying to expose it to another address (the emulator), you have to change what address it listens on.

Comment: @jirungaray I'm using Android Studio rather than Eclipse. I'm not sure if that's what you mean?

Comment: @saiyr could you go a little more in depth about how to do this?

Comment: if the problem is on your endpoints we'll need to see your endpoint code and the console log when you run your local server.

Comment: @SolomonPowell dev_appserver.py --host=0.0.0.0 for Python or dev_appserver.sh --address=0.0.0.0 for Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a tough few days, i found that the problem was that I needed to change my rootUrl from `http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/` to my appspot domain. Now I'm getting the Hello World message.